# How to check if specific Android SDK component is installed or not via command line

Tags: android, command-line-interface, android-sdk-tools

Given:

- I have installed Android SDK available in PATH
- I have installed some of the components by id (e.g. `android-23`, `extra-android-support`, `sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19`, etc) using command `android update sdk -u -a -t some-ids`

Question:

> How to check using command line if those components are installed or not, based on exact same IDs as I installed them?

Bonus:
It can be done without internet connection

---

I'm going to use it in my Ansible Playbook script. I need it to avoid running installation command if they already exists for idempotency. Although the `android update sdk` will not install already installed items, it always query remote android repository beforehand which will be unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's pretty old question, but I was facing the same problem for a while and couldn't find the answer.

So I've done it in my own ansible role (here: "**android_sdk**") by using local facts.
The steps you need to do are:

1. Collect some variable from local facts (in eg. defaults/main.yml):

   ```
   android_sdk_installed: "{{ ansible_local.android_sdk.sdks_installed
                              if (ansible_local|d() and ansible_local.android_sdk|d() and
                                  ansible_local.android_sdk.sdks_installed|d([]))
                              else [] }}"
   ```
2. Install specified SDKs / build-tools / etc

   ```
   - name: Install Android SDKs for applicable releases
     shell: /bin/bash -l -c 'echo y | android -s update sdk -u -a -t "{{ item }}"'
     with_items:
       - "{{ android_sdk_tools }}"
     when: item not in android_sdk_installed
     register: sdk_install_res
   ```

   Where **android_sdk_tools** is for example set to:

   ```
   android_sdk_tools:
     - "build-tools-23.0.2"
     - "build-tools-19.1.0"
   ```
3. Modify local variable **android_sdk_installed** (i know it's pretty ugly - it's just for filtering the output from previous step for a clean view)

   ```
   - name: Set local android_sdk_installed fact
     set_fact: android_sdk_installed="{{ android_sdk_installed|d([]) + [item.item|d()] }}"
     with_items: |
       {% set items=[] %}
       {% for item in sdk_install_res.results %}
       {% if item.item is defined %}{% if item.rc is defined %}
       {% if items.append({'item':item.item,'rc':item.rc}) %}{% endif %}
       {% endif %}{% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
       {{ items | to_nice_json }}
     when: sdk_install_res is defined and item.rc == 0
   ```
4. Save the local facts (it's based on the code from [DebOps Ansible project](https://github.com/debops/))

   ```
   - name: Make sure that Ansible local facts directory is present
     file:
       path: '/etc/ansible/facts.d'
       state: 'directory'
       owner: 'root'
       group: 'root'
       mode: '0755'

   - name: Save android_sdk local facts
     template:
       src: 'etc/ansible/facts.d/android_sdk.fact.j2'
       dest: '/etc/ansible/facts.d/android_sdk.fact'
       owner: 'root'
       group: 'root'
       mode: '0644'
     register: android_sdk_register_local_facts

   - name: Gather facts if they were modified
     action: setup
     when: android_sdk_register_local_facts.changed
   ```

   Where the content of the template file "**android_sdk.fact.j2**" is:

   ```
   {% set android_sdk_tpl_sdks_installed = [] %}
   {% if (ansible_local|d() and ansible_local.android_sdk|d() and
          ansible_local.android_sdk.sdks_installed|d()) %}
   {%   for element in ansible_local.android_sdk.sdks_installed %}
   {%     set _ = android_sdk_tpl_sdks_installed.append(element) %}
   {%   endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% for element in android_sdk_installed or [] %}
   {%       set _ = android_sdk_tpl_sdks_installed.append(element) %}
   {% endfor %}
   {
   "sdks_installed": {{ android_sdk_tpl_sdks_installed | unique | sort | to_nice_json }}
   }
   ```

**Hope it helps, cheers! :)**